React Native: Error during account creation with Appwrite - cyclical structure in JSON object
I'm working on a React Native project using Appwrite for user authentication. I'm encountering an error when trying to submit a registration form. The error message is:
Error during account creation: [TypeError: cyclical structure in JSON object]

Here is the relevant code:
SignUp Component:
import { View, Text, ScrollView, Image, Alert } from 'react-native';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import { images } from '../../constants';
import FormField from '../../components/FormField';
import CustomButton from '../../components/CustomButton';
import { Link, useRouter } from 'expo-router';
import { createUser } from '../../lib/appwrite';

const SignUp = () => {
  const [form, setForm] = useState({
    username: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
  });
  const [isSubmitting, setIsSubmitting] = useState(false);
  const router = useRouter();

  const submit = async () => {
    if (!form.username || !form.email || !form.password) {
      Alert.alert('Error', 'Please fill in all the fields');
      return;
    }

    setIsSubmitting(true);

    try {
      const result = await createUser(form.email, form.password, form.username);
      router.replace('/home');
    } catch (error) {
      Alert.alert('Error', error.message);
    } finally {
      setIsSubmitting(false);
    }
  }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView className="bg-primary h-full">
      <ScrollView>
        <View className="w-full justify-center min-h-[85vh] px-4 my-6">
          <Image source={images.logo} resizeMode='contain' className='w-[115px] h-[35px]' />
          <Text className='text-white text-2xl text-semibold mt-10 font-psemibold'>Sign up to Aora</Text>
          
          <FormField
            title="Username"
            value={form.username}
            handleChangeText={(e) => setForm({ ...form, username: e })}
            otherStyles="mt-10"
          />
          
          <FormField
            title="Email"
            value={form.email}
            handleChangeText={(e) => setForm({ ...form, email: e })}
            otherStyles="mt-7"
            keyboardType="email-address"
          />

          <FormField
            title="Password"
            value={form.password}
            handleChangeText={(e) => setForm({ ...form, password: e })}
            otherStyles="mt-7"
          />

          <CustomButton 
            title='Sign Up'
            handlePress={submit}
            containerStyles='mt-7'
            isLoading={isSubmitting}
          />

          <View className="justify-center pt-5 flex-row gap-2">
            <Text className='text-lg text-gray-100 font-pregular'>Have an account already?</Text>
            <Link href='/sign-up' className='text-lg font-psemibold text-secondary'>Sign In</Link>
          </View>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

export default SignUp;

Appwrite Integration:
import { Account, Client, ID } from "react-native-appwrite";

export const appwriteConfig = {
  endpoint: "https://cloud.appwrite.io/v1",
  projectId: "*****",
  platform: "****",
};

const client = new Client();

client
  .setEndpoint(appwriteConfig.endpoint)
  .setProject(appwriteConfig.projectId)
  .setPlatform(appwriteConfig.platform);

const account = new Account(client);

export async function createUser(email, password, username) {
  if (!email) throw new Error("Email is required");
  if (!password) throw new Error("Password is required");
  if (!username) throw new Error("Username is required");

  try {
    const userId = ID.unique();
    const newAccount = await account.create(userId, email, password, username);
    return newAccount;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error during account creation:", error);
    throw new Error(error.message);
  }
}

I've verified that the form data is being populated correctly.
Steps I've Taken:

Ensured all fields are filled before submission.
Tried to log the form data and confirmed there are no obvious
issues.
Checked Appwrite documentation and confirmed that the API endpoint
and project ID are correct.

Questions:

What could be causing the "cyclical structure in JSON object" error
during the account creation process?
Please are there any specific steps or checks I can perform to resolve this
issue?
Is there a better way to handle form submission with Appwrite in
React Native to avoid such errors?

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!
